# Does api work like bytcode to provide multi-platform functionality

Tags: api, bytecode

I've recently come across the term api and from what I have  known api is a interface that connects/integrates between two programs and it can run on any platform.

And again from java we know that it turns it's source code into bytecodes and this bytecode can run on any platforms since it is platform independent.

So my question is does api work/run just like as a bytecode to provide multi-platform functionality

And if not is there any similarities between them or thier process? If please anyone could explain it to me it would be a great help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: **API** is a word which describes a relatively large field. You might be able to find out more about it in the [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_programming_interface).

Comment: API and bytecode are entirely different things. Normally, questions like “what are the differences between them?” are asked about terms having at least some common starting point.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

API does not work like bytecode

Actually, API and Bytecodes are a completely different thing

For Bytecode,
let's try to understand it in java. java compiler compiles a java program then produce bytecode. Then the bytecode is interpreted by java interpreter in different machines and generate different executable files as the requirement of different machines and os.

this is how java maintains it's multi-platform property

Now, API,

API stands for Application Programming Interface. An API is a software intermediary that allows two applications to talk to each other.  In other words, an API is the messenger that delivers your request to the provider that you’re requesting it from and then delivers the response back to you.

there are many types of API's out there

but I think you are referring to Web API and it's multi-platform functionality and how it works.

A Web API is an application programming interface for either a web server or a web browser

A Web API works as server-client architecture.

client request to server through **HTTP protocol**, server responds to client through **HTTP protocol**

actually whole api service is provided through **HTTP protocol**, and this api service can provide to **any device** using HTTP protocol

this has nothing to do with bytecode